# Sublime TFS Settings

Tags: sublimetext3, azure-devops

When working with Classic ASP, Sublime is AWESOME, but what has been stopping me so far is the fact that at work we use Visual Studio Team Services (previously Team Foundation Service) to Check-out / Check-in files we edit and work on and that goes rather well with Visual Studio 2012 that we use. But VS is so slow compared to Sublime especially when all I care about is editing text.

Today I found out that Sublime Text (I use Version 3) has a plugin for TFS! So I installed it (also installed the [TFS Power Tools 2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b1ef7eb2-e084-4cb8-9bc7-06c3bad9148f)). But now I'm confused as I ***can not see any visual clues*** to my files like I do with Visual Studio 2012, so I don't know what files are up to date, and what files need checking in ... etc.

After reading the [official page](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Sublime%20TFS) of the Sublime TFS plugin. I understand that I need to set `tf_path` somewhere! The page though doesn't say where and in what format :( I am lost.

Where do I set the `tf_path` and in what format?

Any help would be great, Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your Sublime Text changes to be seen in Visual Studio Team Explorer, then you can change your Workspace to a local one.

For more information: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/decide-between-using-local-server-workspace

Like this, you can use Sublime Text for editing and have as much ST windows as you want. And you can do the check-in of files using the Team Explorer. This is how I work. One Visual Studio with one or more Sublime Text windows. Very light-weight, efficient and productive.

Answer (score 7):

Navigate to `Preferences -> Package Settings -> Sublime TFS` and open both `Settings - Default` and `Settings - User` (which will be an empty file). Copy the entire contents of the default settings file to the user file, then change any paths to reflect your personal setup. Save the user file (you are not allowed to modify the default file, just close it), restart Sublime for good luck, and you should be all set.

Comment: Thanks, I did as you suggested. Does the plugin not provide any visual cues on whether I need to do a check-in ... etc